# button with shadow animation or with bouncing background

Tags: android, android-animation, androiddesignsupport, android-designer

How can I design a bouncing background animation in Android? I want to this animation without any event raise.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `bouncing_bg.xml` in your app's **`drawable`** folder.

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#aeaeae" />
```

and add the following line to the `View` to which you want to show the effect.

```
android:foreground="@drawable/bouncing_bg"
```

**Note :** This will only work in API Level 21 and above.